# Help on Proof By Induction

Tags: induction, solution-verification

We had to prove the following algorithm by induction:

$ a^n = a^{n/2*2} = a^{n/2}*a^{n/2} $     if $n$ is even

$ a^n = a^{\frac {n-1}2*2}*a = a^{\frac {n-1}2} * a^{\frac {n-1}2} * a $     if $n$ is odd

I need to prove this by induction.

My Solution:

Base Case: Let $n = 1$: $a^1 = a$  (Proven for $n = 1$)

Induction Hypothesis: Let this be true for all integers upto n. If $n$ is even break it into parts and as those values must be less than $n$ it would be true for them and then multiply that by a (Base Case.)

Same for when is odd.

Hence proven.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: For the base case, you have to also show that it is true for $n=2$ since you have two different cases in your problem.

Comment: But otherwise is it correct?

Comment: It is correct provided that when you say $n$ is even, you are proving the case $n+1$ is odd.